# Thread vanishes without a trace

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, yield

I'm trying to debug an issue. We have few Threads that work on data from a BoundedLinkedQueue. After processing one record, the current thread executes `Thread.currentThread().yield()`.

Now, once a while it is observed that one of the thread just vanishes ! I have traced the logs to find that such a "vanishing" thread works till the yield statement. After that no traces of that thread are found - nor any errors or exceptions are thrown near the last log seen for the thread.

Can anyone give any pointers for debugging directions ? Is the usage of the yield correct ? Is the yield a reliable statement ? This is because I found out [this](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/yield.shtml) article suggesting to avoid the yield statement ? Has anyone seen such a condition before ?

**Edit:** On some research, it seems that try/catch may miss some exceptions and those would be just put into System.err which may not be noticeable in a multi-threaded environment. Thanks to @JVerstry for the pointer, I have set uncaughtexceptionhandler for the Thread. The build and run process takes long. Will update more once I have something concrete.
Here are few links that talk about UncaughtExceptionHandler:

- [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://captainlog.tk/threaduncaughtexceptionhandler-new)
- [Catching Uncaught Exceptions in JDK 1.5](http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/catching_uncaught_exceptions_in_jdk_5.shtml)
- [Java theory and practice: Hey, where'd my thread go ?](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0924/index.html)
- [Know the JVM Series 1 - The Uncaught Exception Handler](http://java.dzone.com/articles/know-jvm-series-%E2%80%93-1-%E2%80%93-uncaught?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20javalobby/frontpage%20%28Javalobby%20/%20Java%20Zone%29)

Comment: what OS/arch are you running on? rationale for using yield?

Comment: No idea why your thread disappears, but yieal is a static method, and always pauses the current thread. You should use `Thread.yield()`

Comment: Could you please post sample snapshot of source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to get a thread dump when this re-occurred and seems that the thread was just blocking on a JDBC call forever - a bug in the jdbc jar. We just replaced the jar with the latest version and seems to have solved it. Thanks all for the valuable inputs - made me learn a lot of new things. Also, now put a query time out to prevent blocking forever.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the article you linked, yield doesn't define whether or not the current quantum is interrupted.  If you yield right before thread exit, the scheduler just might complete the quantum for the thread causing the thread to exit immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Yield does not make threads vanish. It is possible that your thread throws an exception and that is not caught. Did you implement an [uncaught exception handler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)? If not, then I recommend you do so. It would explain your problem (unless the thread ends up naturally and your code does not do what you think it should do).

Comment: @JVerstry... Thanks. Seems we don't have the uncaught exception handler. However there is a top level try-catch block that catches Exception object. Unfortunately nothing is being caught here.

Comment: If you are sure your try/catch is well implemented, then your code most probably does not do what you think it does. Otherwise, I would give a try at an uncaught exception handler. It is easy to implement. If you still don't catch anything, then you are sure the bug is in the coding.

Answer (score 0):

1. What occurs after the yield?  Will the thread exit or will it attempt to process another piece of data from the queue?
2. You should verify that the what is being called after the yield is actually being called with logging.
3. How do you know the thread has exited?  Have you verified by using by looking at a stack trace (Use Jstack)?
4. Lastly why are you using yield at all?  I assume your BoundedLinkedQueue allows threads to retrieve data in a thread-safe manner, or blocks if the queue is empty.  Why not just let the JVM manange thread scheduling?

Comment: 1. The thread processes another piece of data. 2. Nothing after the yield is logged (This happens once a while and some random thread vanishes) 3. I see no stack trace even with the outermost try/catch statement. Hence I have added the uncaughtexceptionhandler hoping to catch it now. 4. Many people suggest the use of yield by well-behaved threads. JVM manages the scheduling but by yield we suggest the scheduler that this may be a good time to take over the cpu.

Comment: @advantej 3. How are you determining that the thread vanishes?  4.  Without empirical evidence i wouldn't assume that using yield will produce better results. 5. How many threads are pulling data from the queue?  6. Have you considered letting an ExecutorService in the java.util.concurrent package manage your threds?

Comment: 3. No trace of thread and no evidence of the task done by the thread 4. This is kind of legacy code and working well with around 100 customers - problem been seen at couple. 5. Not more than 15 threads. 6. No. People are scared of touching legacy working code :D